# PyMySQLでの問合せ結果がテーブルデータ変更後も変化しない

Tags: python, mysql

PythonでのPyMySQLに関してですが、テーブルからユーザー名を取得する関数を作ったのですが、そのユーザーをmysqlから消しても、関数が返す値が同じです。何がいけないのでしょうか？

以下が作った関数です

```
import sys
import time
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='user',
                       password='password',
                       db='database',
                       charset='utf8')

def get_user():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = """SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=testuser"""
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.close()
    return result


def worker():
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(get_user())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopeed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker()
```

testuserを消した後、get_user()を実行すると、テーブルには存在しないのに返ってきてます。なぜでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コードを一目で見ると、一つの問題は`'`のマークのことにあると思います。特に、この行：

```
>>> testuser = "me"
>>> query = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='testuser''
```

この関数を実行すると、`SyntaxError`が発生するでしょう。例えば：

```
>>> query = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='testuser''
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    query = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='testuser''
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

そしたら、`SELECT`の`query`が正確に実行されていないと思いますので、他に問題が発生する可能性もあると思います。

そのために、下記の方はどうですか。

```
query = """SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='%s'""", (testuser)
```

出力の例：

```
>>> testuser = "me"
>>> query = """SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='%s'""", (testuser)
>>> query
("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='%s'", 'me')
```

---

#### 更新

もっと調べてみると、これは「キャッシュ」のことにつながっている問題ではないでしょうか。特に、「`autocommit`」という設定に[関係があるかもしれません](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/76)。しかし、[suzukis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/5793/suzukis)さんの回答のように、`commit`のことはやはり[`MySQL Query Cache`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/query-cache.html)に関係がないようですが。

それにしても、下記のメソードを呼び出すと、「キャッシュっぽい効果」を避けることが出来るようです。

`conn.autocommit(True)`

[このスレでは、martaaayさんの説明](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/76#issuecomment-10236696)のように、`autocommit(False)`という設定は最新のチェンジを無視して、次の`commit`を実行する前に、前のデータを使用する状態になってしまうのです。他方では、`autocommit(True)`という設定は自動的に最新のトランザクションを`commit`して、これからは最新の`commit`されたデータを使用することが出来ます。

将来の参照のために、`autocommit`のこと自体については[suzukisさんの説明](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/23328/4129)と共に、MySQLのトランザクションについての[リファレンス](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/commit.html)もあると思います。トランザクションということ自体は大切な概念で、特に[ACID](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6))には[役に立ちます](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740307)。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そのとおりにしてもダメでした。
usersテーブルにテストユーザーがある時点で一度実行して、
"""SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='%s'""", (testuser)
とするとユーザーが存在するので返ってくるのですが、
テーブの中身を消してもその関数は値を返し続けます..

Comment: そもそも、この関数が実行されているのは確実でしょうか？summeaさんが指摘するように、SyntaxErrorが発生するはずです。それが発生していなかったというのが不思議です。呼び出し元で別の関数を呼んでいるとか無いですか？

Comment: はい。できています。変数でユーザー名を指定しても結果は同じです。

Comment: @Roar その場合は、ユーザーの変数って、なんの変数でしょうか・・・例えば、それは`get_user()`の`return`の値ですか。または、`testuser`の変数ですか。mjyさんが言っていたように、`get_user()`の代わりに、別の関数を呼んでいるのでしょうか？

Comment: @summea はい、testuserの変数になります。
`testuser = "testuser"`
`query = """SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='%s'""", (testuser)`としてもできません。

Comment: @Roar それはそうですけど、`get_user()`の関数自体を除くと、実行する時はどうなるでしょうか。別の関連しているコードもあるのでしょうか。

Comment: @summea すいません。コード全体を記載しました！よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @Roar あと、関数が返す値はなんでしたっけ？

Comment: @summea ユーザー名です！。
テーブルにユーザーがあるときにプログラムを実行すると返ってくるのですが、ユーザーを消した後でも表示され続けます・・・

Comment: @Roar ユーザー名って、「`testuser`」ですか？

Comment: @summea はい。testuserっていう文字列が返ってきます。

Comment: @Roar どうも！じゃ、上記の回答をとうとう更新しました。その`autocommit`のメソードはRoarさんの場合には役に立つといいですね。

Comment: @summea  わざわざ調べくださって本当にありがとうございます！
`conn.autocommit(True)`を追加することでうまく動きました！
本当にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3):

autocommitを有効にしたら期待したとおりの動作になったということで、それはトランザクションによるものです。

トランザクションというのはデータベースにおける一連の処理の塊のことで、「コミット」という操作をすることでDBに反映が永続化されます。また、「ロールバック」という操作で処理を取り消すことも出来ます。

autocommit(自動コミット)が無効の場合、明示的にcommitないしはrollbackするまではトランザクションの内部にいることになります。ここで、他のトランザクションによりDBが変更されたとしても、その変更を読み取ることは出来ません。(細かいことを言うとトランザクション分離レベルにもよる)

autocommitを有効にすると、1つクエリを発行した時点でトランザクションが完結します。他のトランザクションによる変更後に発行されたクエリではその変更を読み取ることが出来ます。

キャッシュとは全く違う概念です。

データベース理論の入門的な内容ですがデータベースのACID特性について学んでもらえば、これがデータベースの信頼性に関わる根本的な部分に関連していて、キャッシュとは全く違うものであることが理解できると思います。

Comment: それはそうですね、commitとキャッシュとは同じことではありません。Roarさんの返した値はいつも同じであったため、この問題はなんとなく「キャッシュ」のことに‌​関係があるかと思っていただけですが。でも、commitする前に、前のデータを使うのは「キャッシュ」みたいな振る舞いですから、「全く違う」とは言い過ぎではないでし‌​ょうか。一応、私の上記の回答には「query cache」のところを編集します。どうも！

Comment: 自分の「キャッシュ」というコメントの意味は、トランスアクションが実行される前に、前の保存されたデータが用いられることのように、「キャッシュ」の場合には（データベースより、普通のキャッシュということで）、新しいデータがキャッシュされる前に、元のキャッシュされたデータが用いられるのですので、MySQLの場合はトランスアクションが`commit`される前の状態は「キャッシュ」っぽいの振る舞いのようですが。

Comment: @summea あなたがキャッシュと呼んでいるものは世代管理されたある特定のバージョンのデータのことです。[MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)について読んでみてください。MySQLもMVCCです。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi MVCCについてのコメントをありがとうございます。